# SQLite and JSTL

Tags: sqlite, jstl

Just out of curiosity, is it possible to connect to an SQLite database from a JSP page using JSTL or is it just for MySql and all the other big DBMS?

I want to implement this simple blog application but would like to use SQLite instead of some big and perhaps heavy database system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JSTL SQL tag library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html) makes use of [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) to connect to a database (also note that JSTL SQL is designed for quick prototyping, not real applications).

JDBC is an abstraction layer over any database. The actual details of the underlying database are handled by a specific driver.

To use SQLite you could give [this driver](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) a try.

Comment: I was using that Driver and it works in normal Java Programs (SE) but for (EE & Web)  i simply apply the data transfer through requests instead. But all in all thanks for the explanation. I get it.